# iTextSharp target=_blank in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am generating PDF in C# using iTextSharp dll. I need to have links, which will be linked to the external PDFs/docs.

Is there a way to facilitate target=_blank mode? All links result in another PDF being rendered within the original PDF browser window.

I use the following c# code:

```
        Anchor tool = new Anchor(new Phrase("some text",fontHead3));
        tool.Reference = "http://www.google.com", false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This concept doesn't exist in PDF. It exists when you are viewing a PDF in a standalone viewer (such as Adobe Reader) where you can have the option to open a PDF in a new PDF viewer window (not a browser window), but when you view the PDF in a browser plugin, you can't tell the browser to open a new window. The PDF doesn't have access to the browser functionality.

This isn't a problem limited to iTextSharp; it's a problem with PDF in general.